# VBA HTMLSelectElement won't set in runtime but will if manual step by stpe

Tags: html, vba

Thank you for your time.

I am trying to get a dropdown list on a WEB page.  When I test my code manually with "F8" it works fine.  When I run it, the object is not created.  Here is part of the code:

```vb
Dim oHTMLDoc As HTMLDocument

Dim oDeptSelect As HTMLSelectElement

Dim DeptSelectID As String

'It navigates to the page without problems

Set oHTMLDoc = oIE.document

Set oDeptSelect = oHTMLDoc.getElementById(DeptSelectID)
```

The oDeptSelect object is "nothing" when I run the code but is the correct selection element when I go through the code line by line with "F8".

Thanks for the help

EDIT - 01 dec 2020
Here is the full code

```vb
Function MAJ_Profs()

Dim oIE As InternetExplorer
Dim oHTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim URL As String
Dim SelectorID As String
Dim DeptNumber As String
Dim oElement As Object
Dim oElements As HTMLElementCollection
Dim DeptSelectID As String
'Dim DeptSelectName As String
Dim oSelector As HTMLButtonElement
Dim oDeptSelect As HTMLSelectElement
Dim oSelOption As Object
Dim TEMP As Variant
Dim Time As Integer

Application.PrintCommunication = True

Time = 20
Set oIE = New InternetExplorer
URL = "http://www.cvm.qc.ca/Pages/bottindupersonnel.aspx"
'Nom des éléments HTML à détecter et numéro du département dans la liste déroulante
SelectorID = "ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_5e3de0d0_f854_4431_9abf_26fcfcafc0c1_radDept"
DeptSelectID = "ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_5e3de0d0_f854_4431_9abf_26fcfcafc0c1_dropDept"
'DeptSelectName = "ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$g_5e3de0d0_f854_4431_9abf_26fcfcafc0c1$dropDept"
DeptNumber = "241"

'Ouverture de IE et navigation vers Bottin du personnel
oIE.Visible = True
oIE.navigate (URL)

Do Until oIE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
Do While oIE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

'Acquisition des infos de la page HTML
Set oHTMLDoc = oIE.document
Do Until oIE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
Do While oIE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

'Activation du sélecteur de liste "Départements"
Set oSelector = oHTMLDoc.getElementById(SelectorID)
oSelector.Click

Do Until oIE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
Do While oIE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

Application.Wait (TimeSerial(Hour(Now()), Minute(Now()), Second(Now()) + Time))

'Sélection du département dans la liste déroulante

'______________________



Set oDeptSelect = oHTMLDoc.getElementById(DeptSelectID)



'-----------------------
Do Until oIE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
Do While oIE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

For Each oSelOption In oDeptSelect.Options
    If InStr(oSelOption.Value, DeptNumber) Then
        oSelOption.Selected = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next oSelOption

oDeptSelect.FireEvent ("onchange")

TEMP = oHTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("simple")

Set oDeptSelect = Nothing
Set oSelOption = Nothing
Set oSelector = Nothing
Set oHTMLDoc = Nothing
Set oIE = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: I forgot what I have tried:  I have embeded in the code line for testing IE READY_STATE,  I have tried Application.Wait for 3 seconds, I have put While IE.busy "do events" lines with the READY_STATE tests.

Comment: I know you say you've waited and it doesn't make a difference, but that's nearly always the explanation when it works with F8 but not when run straight through.  Usually there's something on the page which is not monitored by ReadyState.  That's pretty typical these days with dynamic content.

Comment: I have reintegrated the Application.Wait and waited for 20sec before the SET oDeptSelect, and still get the same result...

Comment: Unlikely but is the webpage public?

Comment: The webpage is accessible to the public.  Here is the URL : http://www.cvm.qc.ca/Pages/bottindupersonnel.aspx.  I can easily click the "Departement" option, but still can't figure out why the htmlselectelement will not SET.

Comment: Here is my full code if it can help.

Comment: Oops... that can't work!

Comment: You can edit your question to add more code